# simulate clustered indexes using XML files

Tags: c#, xml, indexing

assume I have 1 table contains data about  (ID, Name, City, Country) in an XML file and I need to simulate clustered index using c# to prove it will enhance the performance of searching I am tasked to create the index on the ID field

what I know about index files is that each line points somewhere in the datafile 
is clustered index works logically another way than like primary index

I tried searching for clustered index and I learned that it exists in database management systems and it will be automatically created with the creation of the primary key I installed SSMS but couldn't reach to the clustered index file I want to know how it looks like or how to simulate it in c# (since it means ordering data physically)?

ty

Comment: I don't know how much it should simulate clustered index, but the start point for you could be that no matter what kind of index, index is always sorted by some key, clustered index is sorted by primary key

Comment: The easiest implementation would be to create 2 xml files, one with sorted data by id and  one unsorted. Then in test program you could parse both files and try to search some record by id and by e.g. city and measure timing

Comment: Clusted index in this case means following 1) You have a xml tag for each county 2) You have a child element for each city.  3) Each City has an element Name and ID.

Comment: sTrenat is sorted xml files by id means it has clustered index on the id?
i understand all of primary index and i can even simulate a file with primary index because it has a shape and points to something but clustered is ordering the data on the physical hardware how can i simualte that 
thank for ur answer and time

Comment: jdweng i don't want it like that i want you to teach me how u reached that conclusion

Comment: https://s33046.pcdn.co/wp-content/uploads/2019/06/basic-clustered-index-binary-tree-b-tree-storage-1.png - take a look at this. I think this is the scheme you want to implement in xml

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try code like below :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;
using System.Data;
using System.Xml.Serialization;
using System.IO;

namespace ConsoleApplication2
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            DateTime startTime;
            DateTime endTime;

            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            dt.Columns.Add("ID", typeof(string));
            dt.Columns.Add("Name", typeof(string));
            dt.Columns.Add("City", typeof(string));
            dt.Columns.Add("Country", typeof(string));

            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { "1", "Bronx", "New York", "USA" });
            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { "2", "Queens", "New York", "USA" });
            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { "3", "Hollywood", "Los Angeles", "USA" });
            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { "4", "Circle Theater", "London", "Great_Britan" });
            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { "5", "Eiffle Tower", "Paris", "France" });

            string ident = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?><Database></Database>";

            XDocument doc = XDocument.Parse(ident);
            XElement database = doc.Root;

            foreach (var country in dt.AsEnumerable().GroupBy(x => x.Field<string>("Country")))
            {
                XElement xCountry = new XElement("Country", country.Key);
                database.Add(xCountry);

                foreach (var city in country.GroupBy(x => x.Field<string>("City")))
                {
                    XElement xCity = new XElement("City", city.Key);
                    xCountry.Add(xCity);
                    foreach (DataRow name in city.AsEnumerable())
                    {
                        XElement xName = new XElement("Name", name.Field<string>("Name"), new XElement("ID", name.Field<string>("ID")));
                        xCity.Add(xName);
                    }
                }
            }

            //simulation no indexing
            List<XElement> xIds = doc.Descendants("ID").ToList();
            startTime = DateTime.Now;
            foreach (DataRow row in dt.AsEnumerable())
            {
                string id = row.Field<string>("ID");

                foreach (XElement xId in xIds)
                {
                    if (id == (string)xId)
                       break;
                }
            }
            endTime = DateTime.Now;
            TimeSpan sim1 = endTime - startTime;

            //simulation with indexing
            StringReader sReader = new StringReader(doc.ToString());

            XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Database));
            Database db = (Database)serializer.Deserialize(sReader);

            startTime = DateTime.Now;

            foreach (DataRow row in dt.AsEnumerable())
            {
                string country = row.Field<string>("Country");
                string city = row.Field<string>("City");
                string name = row.Field<string>("Name");
                string ID = row.Field<string>("ID");

                Country cCountry = db.Country.Where(x => x.name == country).FirstOrDefault();

                City cCity = cCountry.City.Where(x => x.name == city).FirstOrDefault();

                Name cName = cCity.Name.Where(x => x.name == name).FirstOrDefault();
                string cID = cName.ID;
            }

            endTime = DateTime.Now;

            TimeSpan sim2 = endTime - startTime;


        }
    }
    public class Database
    {
        [XmlElement]
        public List<Country> Country { get; set; }
    }
    public class Country
    {
        [XmlText]
        public string name { get; set; }

        [XmlElement]
        public List<City> City { get; set; }
    }
    public class City
    {
        [XmlText]
        public string name { get; set; }

        [XmlElement]
        public List<Name> Name { get; set; }
    }
    public class Name
    {
        [XmlText]
        public string name { get; set; }

        public string ID { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Here is the results :

```
 <Database>
   <Country>
    USA
     <City>
      New York
       <Name>
        Bronx
        <ID>1</ID>
      </Name>
      <Name>
        Queens
        <ID>2</ID>
      </Name>
    </City>
    <City>
      Los Angeles
      <Name>
        Hollywood
        <ID>3</ID>
      </Name>
    </City>
  </Country>
  <Country>
    Great_Britan
    <City>
      London
      <Name>
        Circle Theater
        <ID>4</ID>
      </Name>
    </City>
  </Country>
  <Country>
    France
    <City>
      Paris
      <Name>
        Effifle Tower
        <ID>5</ID>
      </Name>
    </City>
  </Country>
</Database>
```

Comment: I don't think this simulates cluster index, it's more like simulation of multicolumn index

Comment: thank u for ur answer i understand the first part of creating datatable
but at "String ident = " i think this will turn the data into xml .
and the data will be outside to inside 
which is not what i am trying to do i already  have an xml file i will put first few lines
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Table Name="Employees">
<Employee>
    <ID>4</ID>
    <Name>d</Name>
    <City>paris</City>
    <Country>france</Country>
</Employee>

Comment: i have like 100 of this and need to "simulate a clustered index around the ID"
this phrase between quotes is what i dnt get. becauseindexes can be done in sql i guess that's why it's called "Simulation"

Comment: sry I can't put the example on the easy-to-read format on the previous comment
according to someone else answer ur code might be the solution for the whole task  
:( i hope it's not i just needed to understand not the answer

Comment: I updated code and changed format a little bit.  Isn't it better to reverse order like I did and put country first instead or like what you did and put ID first?  Clustering means to group by types.  The searching is going to be by country/city/name  not by ID.  People do not lookup by ID.  Suppose you want to find a Zip (Postal) Code.

Comment: the thing i am tasked to make a performance test on the file with id then with city

Comment: my idea about the index is it's a file contains references to certain places in the data file
is clustered index not a file in itself but just a primary key being ordered inside the data file?

Comment: I updated code to do a simulation without indexing and with indexing to compare times.  For indexing I serialized the xml.  So first simulation gets each row from datatable and then searches xml for the id without any indexing.  Second simulation goes the each row from datatable and then finds ID using the serialized classes.  My times did not include the time to create the indexes.

Answer (score 0):

The closest data structure in .NET to a Clustered BTree is the `SortedSet<T>`:

> Starting with the .NET Framework 4, the SortedSet class provides a
>   self-balancing tree that maintains data in sorted order after
>   insertions, deletions, and searches.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/collections/sorted-collection-types

You could traverse the XML document and add the XElement items to a `SortedSet<XElement>` or a `SortedSet<MyEntity>` with a custom comparer to order by ID.